# node: bad option: --experimental-worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, worker-thread

I am trying to experiment with worker_threads in `node.js`.

```
const { Worker, isMainThread, parentPort } = require('worker_threads');
if (isMainThread) {
    // This code is executed in the main thread and not in the worker.

    // Create the worker.
    const worker = new Worker(__filename);
    // Listen for messages from the worker and print them.
    worker.on('message', (msg) => { console.log(msg); });
} else {
    // This code is executed in the worker and not in the main thread.

    // Send a message to the main thread.
    parentPort.postMessage('Hello world!');
}
```

I save the above code in `index.js` and run `node  --experimental-worker index.js` on terminal. 
I get the following error:

> node: bad option: --experimental-worker.

I have `v8.16.0` of node installed in my mac.

Comment: can you share documentation? cant find it pre v10.5, added 10.5. https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_class_worker

Comment: Hey @Estradiaz, I upgraded the node version and its working now. Thanks!

Comment: @estradiaz Please turn your comment into an answer

Answer (score 8):

The [`Worker`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_class_worker) class was added in nodejs v10.5.0.

To use `--experimental-worker` one will need at least nodejs v10.5.0

With [nodejs v12.x](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_threads) it is stable and can be used without `--experimental-worker`

Downloads: [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Version Manager: [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue, but as suggested by @Estradiaz I upgraded my node version from v8.16.0 to v.12.13.1 by

1. nvm install 12.13.1
2. nvm use 12.13.1
   then the issue solved.